# Simple question about full time derivative

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Let's have full time derivative equation

$$
\frac{F(\mathbf r (t), \mathbf p (t), t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}.
$$

Can I represent this equation as

$$
F(\mathbf r (t), \mathbf p (t), t) = \int \left( \frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\right)dt
$$
and, if I can't, why not?

In principle, this expression is equivalent to the identity

$$
F = \int \frac{dF}{dt}dt.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$dF= \frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} dt+ \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } dt+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt$$
$$dF= \bigg(\frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\bigg)dt$$
From which it follows that
$$\frac{dF}{dt}= \frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$
And since
$$F=\int dF=\int \bigg(\frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\bigg)dt=\int\frac{dF}{dt}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\frac{F(\mathbf r (t), \mathbf p (t), t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$$

Integrating both sides from $s$ to $s'$, $s<s'$, we have that $$F(r(s'),p(s'),s')-F(r(s),p(s),s)=\int_s^{s'}\frac{\partial \mathbf r }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf r} + \frac{\partial \mathbf p }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf p } + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt$$